# How do I return my output instead of print?

Tags: python, string, return

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    adjusted_string = sentence.split()
    for i in adjusted_string:
        if len(i) > 5:
            print(i[::-1], end = ' ')
        else:
            print(i, end = ' ')
```

The problem is asking to take a string and return the same string but, with all the five letter words or more in reversed

Comment: Have you tried using the `return` keyword instead of calling `print`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    splitted_string = sentence.split()
    reversed_fives = [s[::-1] if len(s) >= 5 else s for s in splitted_string]
    return " ".join(reversed_fives)
```